# Where can I find Spectreman End Credits Poster to Buy or Download?

Tags: merchandise

In the classic *Spectreman*, Japanese action series, the ending credits roll while a huge poster of an epic fight between spectreman and a dragon(?) roll, showing Dr. Gori, Karas, amidst a wrecked city.

I tried, googled, and busted my fingers trying to find that image in high resolution, but to no avail.

Tried even some searches in Japanese, but that went to nothing really.

This youtube video shows the closing credits: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEBtjKNwZIE

A small excerpt of said image can be found here:

[image: ED image]

That poster would be epic to have on my wall, so thanks.

Comment: Putting aside the fact that you're asking about the tokusatsu show (which is off-topic in terms of the scope of this site -- SciFi.SE would be a better match), it's unlikely that any physical copies exist and if they did they'd be a rare collectible. This show came out in an era where digital scanning was not commonplace, so it's unlikely there are digital copies made. You best bet would be to rip the images from the [DVD set](http://www.yesasia.com/us/p-pro-dvd-must-collection-spectreman-custom-component-box-dvd-boxset/1004771672-0-0-0-en/info.html) and print it yourself.

Comment: @Krazer I really looked hard where to ask for it, but this were the best shot. If you want to close the question as off-topic, be my guest.

Comment: The question has found its place on [SciFi.SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53468/was-the-spectreman-end-credits-background-ever-released-as-a-poster-or-full-imag) and was answered recently.

Comment: @AkiTanaka let old skeletons lie... It was me on my early stack days.